# Safe neo4j queries with dynamic node labels [python driver]

Tags: python, neo4j, networkx

I am trying to write code which writes networkx graphs into neo4j. Currently I am using string injections, but I know these are unsafe.

For example, here is some of my code extending networkx's DiGraph class to load nodes into a neo4j instance. The driver is set upon graph object creation.

```
def store_in_neo(self):
    '''
    Add all nodes/edges in the current DiGraph to the neo4j connected DBMS.
    
    Ignores identical nodes/edges that are already stored in the DBMS.
    '''
    
    with self.driver.session() as session:
        session.write_transaction(self.add_new_nodes)
        session.write_transaction(self.add_new_edges)
            
def add_new_nodes(self):
    for i in range(len(self.nodes)):
        node_name = list(self.nodes)[i]
        node_label = self.nodes[node_name]['data']['label']
            
        query = (
        f"OPTIONAL MATCH (n:{node_label} \{name: {node_name} \}\n"
        "RETURN n"
        )
            
        #if the node wasn't matched, add node
        if not query:
            write_query = (
            f"CREATE (n:{node_label} \{name: {node_name} \}"
            )
        else:
            continue
```

neo4j's documentation suggests the use of parameters for safely injecting dynamic query options at runtime. However, parameters cannot be used for labels, relationship types, or property keys:

"Parameters cannot be used for the following constructs, as these form part of the query structure that is compiled into a query plan:

• property keys; so, MATCH (n) WHERE n.$param = 'something' is invalid

• relationship types

• labels"

The only part of my schema that is defined for this networkx extension is that there are  'name' and 'color' attributes added to 'data'. This enables me to hardcode in a match on 'name'. So I should be able to use a $param to make the `node_name` injection safe.

But is there a safe way for me to replace the `node_label` portion of my code? This is something I need to be dynamically added at runtime because the node & edge schemae are created in Python, not the neo4j instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this value: and see how the query returns all nodes.  node_label = "Person) RETURN n //".  The query becomes OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n // {name: Keanu }\nRETURN n  and it commented out before name.

Comment: @jose_bacoy exactly, that's what I'm trying to prevent. See my answer below for my current solution. I'm looking for something hopefully more rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use py2neo but ideally I'd like to directly write the queries, with some form of safely escaping the `node_label` injection.

The best solution I can see right now is:

```
def add_new_nodes(self):
    for i in range(len(self.nodes)):
        node_name = list(self.nodes)[i]
        node_name.replace('`', '').replace(';', '') #prevent ending the backtick escape, or early termination
        node_label = self.nodes[node_name]['data']['label']
        node_label.replace('`', '').replace(';', '') #prevent ending the backtick escape, or early termination
            
        query = (
        f"OPTIONAL MATCH (n:`{node_label}` \{name: `{node_name}` \}\n"
        "RETURN n"
        )
            
        #if the node wasn't matched, add node
        if not query:
            write_query = (
            f"CREATE (n:`{node_label}` \{name: `{node_name}` \}"
            )
        else:
            continue
```

Of course, for `node_name` I can change this to a parameter. But I'm not sure if this solution is bulletproof?

Source: https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/having-a-label-as-a-parameter-in-a-cypher-query-efficiently/td-p/26815.

Comment: Also sanitize space, forward slash, parenthesis and curly brackets, aside from backtick and semi-colon. These are nonChars that can be used in injections. Goodluck!

Comment: Btw, when you do a MERGE, you don't need to check if exists or not. MERGE is a MATCH/CREATE.  If the node label and node name exists, then it will be not created.

Comment: @jose_bacoy Thanks so much! Will do. Can you point me to some deeper reading about sanitizing neo4j injections? The neo4j website mostly talked about $params which weren't useful to me here. Also great to know about MERGE, I'm still new to Cypher so I didn't realize that existed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `MERGE` statement in your query. This essentially follows the same logic that you have in your code, if the node is already present do nothing, if not create it. You can read about that more here: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/

As for the main part of your question, it is possible to merge nodes with dynamic labels using Neo4j's APOC library. In particular you may find this procedure useful: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.merge/apoc.merge.node/

Last thing, batching the writes to the DB will improve the performance of what you're doing, check out this thread for more: https://community.neo4j.com/t5/neo4j-graph-platform/improving-data-writing-efficiency-in-python/td-p/39520

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You can escape labels with backticks. Backticks in the label must be escaped with two backticks. So if you have a variable `label` that you want to embed in the query (as in `MATCH (n:$label) RETURN n` or similar, which won't work as you wrote) you can instead compute ``` escaped_label = label.replace("\"", r"\u005C").replace("`", "``") ``` and then do string concatenation or interpolation to build the query. For example `` query = f"MATCH (n:`{escaped_label}`) RETURN n" ``. Note how `\u0060` also needs treatment because otherwise the server would unescape this sequence into a backtick.

⚠️ word of warning: generally, as you've mentioned, it's not a good idea to use string interpolation or concatenation for building any database queries (regardless of the DBMS in question) as you can make your code vulnerable to query injections way too easily. However, in this case, there is no other way and if you are absolutely sure about the required escaping it can still be done safely.